# Including start_sasl.boot when creating a release with rebar3

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, rebar

When I create a release with rebar3 (`rebar3 release` or `rebar3 tar`) and that I include ERTS, the `start_sasl.boot` script is missing and prevents me from starting my application.

```
# ./erts-8.2.1/bin/erl -boot start_sasl [...]

{"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot get bootfile','start_sasl.boot'}}
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

My current `rebar.config` section for releases:

```
{relx, [
  {release, {my_app, "1.0.0"}, [my_app]},
  {dev_mode, false},
  {include_erts, true},
  {extended_start_script, false},
  {generate_start_script, false},
  {overlay, [
    {copy, "priv/scripts/nodetool", "bin"},
    {copy, "priv/scripts/run", "bin"}
  ]}
]}.
```

Is there a setting that I'm missing that to include `start_sasl.boot` in the release directory?